# What are the Power BI gateway data compression and limits?

Tags: powerbi

1. Does Power BI gateway perform any compression on the data before sending it out to power bi service?
2. Is there any limit to pre or post compression data size that the gateway can process?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes it does
2. Power BI service uses a defined limit of 10 GB uncompressed data per table allowed for a model without Premium, regardless of compression potential, with a post-compression limit of 1 GB.

Comment: Please give the reference documentation which says so

Comment: https://intellitect.com/blog/power-bi-data-compression/

Comment: It doesn't say that gateway does compression